# net.sf.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to javax.servlet.http.Cookie

Tags: java, casting

I'm trying to store some `List` objects into the JSONArray and read it back.

It's working fine if it is `List<String>`. But if I'm trying same with `List<Cookie>` it's not working.

The working example is here:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import net.sf.json.JSONArray;

public class Test {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {

        JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();

        List<String> arrLst = new ArrayList<String>();

        arrLst.add( "one" );
        arrLst.add( "two" );

        jsonArr.add( arrLst );

        Iterator<List> it1 = jsonArr.iterator();

        while ( it1.hasNext() ) {

            List<String> fg = (List<String>) it1.next();

            fg.forEach( str -> {

                System.out.println( str );
            } );
        }
    }
}
```

Output for the above code is:

```
one
two
```

I'm changing above code slightly:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import net.sf.json.JSONArray;

public class Test {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {

        JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();
        List<Cookie> arrLst = new ArrayList<Cookie>();

        arrLst.add( new Cookie( "one", "1" ) );
        arrLst.add( new Cookie( "two", "2" ) );

        jsonArr.add( arrLst );

        Iterator<List> ite = jsonArr.iterator();

        while ( ite.hasNext() ) {

            List<Cookie> cookieLst = (List<Cookie>) ite.next();

            cookieLst.forEach( cookie -> {

                System.out.println( cookie.getName() );
            } );
        }
    }
}
```

Output for the above code is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to javax.servlet.http.Cookie
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:34)
```

What I can to make it work out?

Comment: Have you tried casting to (Cookie) inside the forEach loop rather than in the while loop?

So in the while loop don't cast to Cookie just use Object and then do the cast to Cookie in the forEach loop

Comment: You're explicitly breaking generic type safety by using a raw `List`. You're getting a compiler warning about exactly this problem.

Comment: @JacquesRamsden I just tried like while ( ite.hasNext() ) {

   List<Object> cookieLst = (List<Object>) ite.next();

   cookieLst.forEach( cookie -> {

    Cookie cok = (Cookie) cookie;

    System.out.println( cok.getName() );
   } );
  } but no use at all. It's giving same error at line Cookie cok = (Cookie)cookie;

Comment: @chrylis I don't get you exactly. But, if that is the case how I can overcome it?

Comment: Downloading eclipse..... please hold.......

Comment: After many many mannyyyy downloads of org.apach library's and still not getting it to work (The first example) I give up. Sorry mate. Just don't have the time now. Why are you saving cookies any way? If you need Key value pares can you not just HashMap rather? ... If that works tho :P

Comment: @JacquesRamsden. Thanks for your contribution. I need to make it work in MVC application. My model will return a JSONObject containing processed information. So fat it's having text information but with the new requirement model should return some cookies information as well to the controller.

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this one out?

Comment: @JacquesRamsden No. I made a workaround way to fill the requirement.